# rational function with distinct roots

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, rational-functions, resultant

Let $r(X)$ be a rational function over $\mathbb{C}$.
Is there (always) a complex number $z$ such that the rational function $r(X)-r(X+z)$ has distinct roots?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).